# Optimizing performance of randomly generated pygame maze game

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, pygame

I made a random maze generator that is also playable. The performance is crap and I'd like to improve it. I'll be working on this for a few more days to make it run better myself, but just thought I'd leave this here if people want to help.

```
import random, sys, time, pygame
from fractions import gcd
from pygame.locals import *
from random import *

#End goal: Make a random labyrinth generator
#Generate random, completable walls

    #Have generate_maze be actually completable (Atm moves before assigning, which creates a lot of problems when moving out of already assigned tiles)

#This is stolen. Credit to John Millikin from stackoverflow.com and john-millikin.com. I'd never come up with a solution this compact
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a

if input('Would you like to enable blind mode (recommended)? y/n >>> ') == 'y':
    blind_mode = True
else: blind_mode = False
tile_amount_multiplier = 1 #!!! NEVER SET ABOVE 2! IF YOU DO, THE RESULTS ARE TOTALLY INTENTIONAL GAME DESIGN THAT I JUST DON'T WANT YOU TO SEE
pygame.init()
window_resolution = 800, 600
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_resolution[0], window_resolution[1]))
score = 0
stag_line_width = 5
line_width = stag_line_width
tile_width_height = gcd(window_resolution[0], window_resolution[1]) // 4 // tile_amount_multiplier
touched = []
wall_drawn = False
player_posx = 0
player_posy = 0
border = window_resolution[0]//100 *2 * tile_amount_multiplier -1, window_resolution[1]//100 *2 * tile_amount_multiplier -1
goal_posx = randint(0, border[0])
goal_posy = randint(0, border[1])
player_pos = player_posx, player_posy
goal_pos = goal_posx, goal_posy
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
tile_amount = window_resolution[0] // tile_width_height * (window_resolution[1] // tile_width_height)

def is_border(coordinates, direction):
    if direction == 'right':
        if coordinates[0] >= border[0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif direction == 'left':
        if coordinates[0] <= 0:
            return True
        else: 
            return False
    elif direction == 'up':
        if coordinates[1] <= 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif direction == 'down':
        if coordinates[1] >= border [1]:
            return True
        else: 
            return False
    else:
        print('You are safe from the end of the fucking world')
        return False
    print('Unexpected error in determining border location. You should probably fix that')

def is_wall(dire):
    if is_border(player_pos, dire) == False:
        for pos in no_wall_tiles:
            if (dire == 'right' or 'left') and ((player_pos[1] == pos[0][1]) or (player_pos[1] == pos[1][1])):
                if dire == 'right':
                    if ((player_pos[0] == pos[0][0]) or (player_pos[0] == pos[1][0])) and (((player_pos[0] + 1) == pos[1][0]) or ((player_pos[0] + 1) == pos[0][0])):
                        return False
                elif dire == 'left':
                    if ((player_pos[0] == pos[0][0]) or (player_pos[0] == pos[1][0])) and (((player_pos[0] - 1) == pos[1][0]) or ((player_pos[0] - 1) == pos[0][0])):
                        return False
            if (dire == 'up' or 'down') and ((player_pos[0] == pos[1][0]) or (player_pos[0] == pos[0][0])):
                if dire == 'up':
                    if ((player_pos[1] == pos[0][1]) or (player_pos[1] == pos[1][1])) and (((player_pos[1] - 1) == pos[1][1]) or ((player_pos[1] - 1) == pos[0][1])):
                        return False
                elif dire == 'down':
                    if ((player_pos[1] == pos[0][1]) or (player_pos[1] == pos[1][1])) and (((player_pos[1] + 1) == pos[1][1]) or ((player_pos[1] + 1) == pos[0][1])):
                        return False
        return True
    else:
        return True

def random_direction():
    digit = randint(1, 4)
    if digit == 1:
        return 'right'
    if digit == 2:
        return 'left'
    if digit == 3:
        return 'up'
    return 'down'


def generate_maze():
    wall_generated = False
    generation_visited = []
    global no_wall_tiles
    no_wall_tiles = []
    generation_pos = [randint(0, border[0]), randint(0, border [1])]
    generation_last_pos = []
    first_run = True
    while wall_generated == False:
        if tuple(generation_pos) in generation_visited:
            is_visited = True
        else:
            is_visited = False
        if is_visited == False:
            generation_visited.append(tuple(generation_pos))
            if first_run == False:
                no_wall_tiles.append((tuple(generation_last_pos), tuple(generation_pos)))
        direction = random_direction()
        generation_last_pos = generation_pos.copy()
        if is_border(tuple(generation_pos), direction) == False: #Checks for bounds
            if direction == 'right': #Checks every direction possible
                generation_last_pos = generation_pos.copy()
                generation_pos[0] += 1
            elif direction == 'left': # ^
                generation_last_pos = generation_pos.copy()
                generation_pos[0] -= 1
            elif direction == 'up': # ^
                generation_last_pos = generation_pos.copy()
                generation_pos[1] -= 1
            elif direction == 'down': # ^
                generation_last_pos = generation_pos.copy()
                generation_pos[1] += 1
        first_run = False
        if len(generation_visited) == tile_amount:
            print(no_wall_tiles)
            wall_generated = True

def is_touched(x):
    return x in touched

def draw_walls():
    opposite_cord = 0
    line_color = 100, 0 , 100
    if blind_mode == True:
        line_color = 0,0,0
    for z in range(window_resolution[0] // tile_width_height):
        global line_width
        coordinatex = window_resolution[0] // 10
        coordinatey = window_resolution[1] // 10
        posx = 0
        for x in range(coordinatex // 10 * 4 * tile_amount_multiplier):
            for i in range(1, 4):
                if i == 1:
                    for coord in no_wall_tiles:
                        if (x, z) in coord and (x, z+1) in coord:
                            should_draw = False
                            break
                        should_draw = True
                    if should_draw == True:
                        pygame.draw.line(window,(line_color),(posx, opposite_cord + tile_width_height), (tile_width_height + posx, opposite_cord + tile_width_height), line_width)
                elif i == 2:
                    for coord in no_wall_tiles:
                        if (x, z) in coord and (x+1, z) in coord:
                            should_draw = False
                            break
                        should_draw = True
                    if should_draw == True:
                        pygame.draw.line(window,(line_color),(posx + tile_width_height, opposite_cord), (posx + tile_width_height, opposite_cord + tile_width_height), line_width)
            posx += tile_width_height
            line_width = stag_line_width
        for y in range(coordinatey // 10 * 4 * tile_amount_multiplier):
            posx += tile_width_height
            line_width = stag_line_width
        opposite_cord += tile_width_height
        posx = 0

def is_victory ():
    if player_pos == goal_pos:
        return True
    return False

def draw_tileset():
    opposite_cord = 0
    for z in range(window_resolution[0] // tile_width_height):
        global line_width
        rect_color = 0,0,0
        rect_coror_perma = rect_color
        coordinatex = window_resolution[0] // 10
        coordinatey = window_resolution[1] // 10
        posx = 0
        for x in range(coordinatex // 10 * 4 * tile_amount_multiplier):
            if goal_posx == x and goal_posy == z:
                line_width = 0
                rect_color = (255, 0, 0)
            elif player_posx == x and player_posy == z:
                rect_color = (0, 0, 255)
                line_width = 0
            elif is_touched((x, z)):
                rect_color = 50,200,200
                line_width = 0
            pygame.draw.rect(window, rect_color, (posx, opposite_cord, tile_width_height, tile_width_height), line_width)
            rect_color = rect_coror_perma
            posx += tile_width_height
            line_width = stag_line_width
        for y in range(coordinatey // 10 * 4 * tile_amount_multiplier):
            if player_posy == z and player_posy == y:
                line_width = 1
            pygame.draw.rect(window,(rect_color),(opposite_cord, posx, tile_width_height, tile_width_height), line_width)
            posx += tile_width_height
            line_width = stag_line_width
        opposite_cord += tile_width_height
        posx = 0

#Dumb ass system to coordinates conversion guide: coord main_coordinate = main_coordinate, secondary coordinate = z

generate_maze()
draw_tileset()
draw_walls()
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    player_pos = player_posx, player_posy
    if is_victory() == True:
        score += 1
        print('Your score is now', score)
        player_posx = 0
        player_posy = 0
        goal_posx = randint(0, border[0])
        goal_posy = randint(0, border[1])
        goal_pos = goal_posx, goal_posy
        touched = []
        generate_maze()
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        draw_tileset()
        draw_walls()
        pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            print('You got a score of', score)
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_a and is_wall('left') == False:
                if player_pos not in touched:
                    touched.append(player_pos)
                player_posx -= 1
                window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                draw_tileset()
                draw_walls()
                pygame.display.update()
            elif event.key == K_d and is_wall('right') == False:
                if player_pos not in touched:
                    touched.append(player_pos)
                player_posx += 1 
                window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                draw_tileset()
                draw_walls()
                pygame.display.update()
            elif event.key == K_s and is_wall('down') == False:
                if player_pos not in touched:
                    touched.append(player_pos)
                player_posy += 1
                window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                draw_tileset()
                draw_walls()
                pygame.display.update()
            elif event.key == K_w and is_wall('up') == False:
                if player_pos not in touched:
                    touched.append(player_pos)
                player_posy -= 1
                window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                draw_tileset()
                draw_walls()
                pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, everything @Carcigenicate said.

Next:

1. Replace strings with constants:

   ```
   LEFT = "l"
   RIGHT = r"

   ...

   if dire == LEFT:
   ```
2. Replace a "complete" list of if statements on directions with a dictionary of lambda functions:

   ```
    _BORDER_CHECK = {
       RIGHT: lambda c, b: c[0] >= b[0],
       LEFT: lambda c, b: c[0] <= 0,
       ...
   }

   def is_border(coordinates, direction):
       return _BORDER_CHECK[direction](coordinates, border)
   ```

   Doing this lets you replace 4 comparisons with a single dictionary lookup, which is implemented in C.
3. Don't use the global symbols `True` and `False` if you can avoid them.

   You may not realize this, but Python treats those as *symbols.* They are not magically replaced in the compiler, as they are in C or Java.

   Older versions of Python would see "True" and do this:

   ```
   load the symbol string "True"
   go a global name lookup
   use the result
   ```

   Newer versions know about constants somewhat, so they do this:

   ```
   fetch the constant "True" (still a global name lookup)
   use the result
   ```

   Here's an example:

   ```
   >>> import dis
   >>> def f(x):
   ...     if x == True:
   ...         print("true")
   ... 
   >>> dis.dis(f)

     2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
                 2 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
                 4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
                 6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
   ```

   On the other hand, if you skip using `True` and `False`, you can get better code, like this:

   ```
   >>> def f(x):
   ...     if x:
   ...         print("true")
   ... 
   >>> dis.dis(f)
     2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
                 2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12
   ```

   That's literally 4 opcodes versus 2. Either 50% or 100% faster, depending on whether you work in marketing...
4. Use `random.choice` to pick a direction.
5. Use `collections.namedtuple` to create a Position class, instead of converting from list to tuple over and over again, and indexing all the time.

   Turn this code:

   ```
   if (dire == 'up' or 'down') and ((player_pos[0] == pos[1][0]) or (player_pos[0] == pos[0][0])):
   ```

   Into something like:

   ```
   if dire in (UP, DOWN) and (player_pos.x == pos[0].x or player_pos.x == pos[1].x):
   ```
6. Write a Position [class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) called `random` that takes border parameters and returns a random location therein. You can use that to get rid of the other calls to `random.randint`.
7. Promote all your "against the wall" code to either global constants (with NAMES_LIKE_THIS) or to an init function that you call from `main`.
8. Add the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block that <strike>[PEP-8](https://www.pep8.org) mentions.</strike> is mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).
9. In `generate_maze`, and other places, stop using lists for unique collections. Use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) instead, which has \$O(1)\$ query time. (Lists have \$O(n)\$ query time for `if x in list`.)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have a couple of questions:
1. #5 is very unclear to me. Could you rephrase the question or maybe provide an example?
2. What's a class method? I tried looking it up but I understand nothing.
3. In #9, do you mean sets? If not, I have no idea what you mean.
4. In #8, I could not find that block in the document. I'm pretty sure I misunderstood, so please clarify.

Comment: I have edited the answer to address most of your questions. Sorry about the PEP-8 confusion-- it's in the documentation. Yes, I meant sets in #9, with the `set` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to just touch on style issues mostly.

```
if input('Would you like to enable blind mode (recommended)? y/n >>> ') == 'y':
    blind_mode = True
else: blind_mode = False
```

This could be made a little cleaner and more succinct. First, I'm personally not a fan of putting things on the same line as `else:`. In the vast majority of cases (here included), I think it hurts readability.

I'd suggest something closer to this though:

```
answer = input('Would you like to enable blind mode (recommended)? y/n >>> ')
blind_mode = answer.lower() == 'y'
```

- I'm using `lower` so the user can enter `'Y'` as well, and it will still match.
- `==` already evaluates to a Boolean value. Using an `if` here to dispatch to `True`/`False` is redundant.

Along the same lines, you have this function:

```
def is_victory ():
    if player_pos == goal_pos:
        return True
    return False
```

The `if` is redundant:

```
def is_victory ():
    return player_pos == goal_pos
```

And also here:

```
line_color = 100, 0 , 100
if blind_mode == True:
    line_color = 0,0,0
```

Can be:

```
line_color = (0, 0, 0) if blind_mode else (100, 0 , 100)
```

And the bits like:

```
if coordinates[0] <= 0:
    return True
else: 
    return False
```

Can simply be:

```
return coordinates[0] <= 0
```

---

```
while wall_generated == False:
```

Would be arguably better as:

```
while not wall_generated:
```

If you ever write `something == True` or `something == False`, you're better off just writing `something` and `not something`. Comparing against `True` and `False` is again redundant.

---

Then directly below that you have:

```
if tuple(generation_pos) in generation_visited:
    is_visited = True
else:
    is_visited = False
```

This would be more succinct as:

```
is_visited = tuple(generation_pos) in generation_visited
```

I'd also rethink if the `tuple` conversion is necessary. You're constantly converting a list to a tuple just to do a comparison. I'd just keep it as a list instead of converting to the coordinates to a tuple, unless you *really* want/need to immutability benefits of tuples.

---

```
if (dire == 'right' or 'left') . . .
. . .
if (dire == 'up' or 'down') . . .
```

This code is actually broken. `dire == 'up' or 'down'` will never (ever) be false. It will always be True. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) for an explanation of why.

You want something like:

```
if (dire in {'right', 'left'}) . . .
```

`{. . .}` is a set, and `in` is doing a membership lookup.

---

```
from random import *
```

Try to limit (or outright avoid) using `from . . . import *` statements like that. Wildcard imports like that have two main problems:

- You're polluting the namespace. Because you're dumping all the names from the module into your file, that reduces what names you have available to you to use, and increases the chance of a name collision.
- It makes it harder for readers of your code to know where functions in your code come from, and what the purpose of the imported modules are.

I'd explicitly import exactly what you need:

```
from random import randint
```

Or, use a qualified import:

```
import random
. . .
random.randint(. . .)
```

Now it's clear what's being import, why you're using the `random` modules, and there is no longer any chance of a collision.

---

You have magic numbers floating around in a few places, like:

```
for y in range(coordinatey // 10 * 4 * tile_amount_multiplier):
```

Why `4`? Why `10`? Why not `40`? If those numbers have well-defined purposes, ideally, they should have a name attached to them.

```
# At the top of your file
MY_MULT = 4          # These are poor names because I don't know their purpose
MY_OTHER_MULT = 10

. . .

max_coord = coordinatey // MY_OTHER_MULT * MY_MULT * tile_amount_multiplier
for y in range(max_coord):
```

When those variables are given proper names, it will be much easier for readers of your code to know what exactly is going on math-wise.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. Could you explain why the `line_color = (0, 0, 0) if blind_mode else (100, 0 , 100)` line works? Maybe how the computer interprets it? To me it looks like it'd produce an error, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Aakoo7 `if` can take two forms: as a statement and as an expression. As a statement like you're use to, it takes the form `if <condition>: <do_if_true> else: <do_if_false>`. When used as an expression however (meaning, we want it to evaluate to a value), it takes the form `<value_if_true> if <condition> else <value_if_false>`.

Comment: @Aakoo7 As another example, here's how a conditional expression (the second form of `if`) can be used to write an `abs` function: `def abs(n): return n if n > 0 else -n`. "The absolute value of `n` is `n` if `n` is greater than 0, else it's `n` multiplied by -1".